# How to set array value into textfield using selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selectize.js

Hello I have a problem regarding selectize. I tried and test this code to ensure that I get a list of email coming from the database.

```html
for(var i = 0; i < e.email.length; i++){
  console.log(e.email[i]);
  var list = e.email[i];
}
```

The results are fine and I get what I want.
But when using selectize...

```html
var $el = $("#poc-email").selectize();
var control = $el[0].selectize;
control.setValue(list);
```

It doesnt work.
I also tried..

```
addOption(list);
refreshItems();
```

and also I tried..

```
addItem(list);
```

but it doesnt work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MY SOLUTIONS IS:

```
for(var i = 0; i < e.email.length; i++){
            control.addOption({text:e.email[i].emails, value:e.email[i].emails});
            control.addItem(e.email[i].emails);
            control.refreshItems();
          }
```